# Object Identity and Equality in Java

Tags: java, compare, equals, hashcode, hash-code-uniqueness

Please take a look at the 2 examples below:

```
String a = new String("hello");
String b = new String("hello");
System.out.println("a.hashCode() - " + a.hashCode());
System.out.println("b.hashCode() - " + b.hashCode());
System.out.println("a == b - " + (a == b));
System.out.println("a.equals(b) - " + (a.equals(b)));
```

Result:

```
a.hashCode() - 99162322
b.hashCode() - 99162322
a == b - false
a.equals(b) - true
```

If I understand it correctly, I have 2 different objects, since word **new** creates object. But we see that the **hashCode** is the same, which means I was wrong. If the hashCode is the same, I understand why `a.equals(b)` is **True**.

However the output of this code:

```
int [] a = {1, 2, 3};
int [] b = {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println("a.hashCode() - " + a.hashCode());
System.out.println("b.hashCode() - " + b.hashCode());
System.out.println("a == b - " + (a == b));
System.out.println("a.equals(b) - " + (a.equals(b)));
```

is different:

```
a.hashCode() - 1627674070
b.hashCode() - 1360875712
a == b - false
a.equals(b) - false
```

Now we have two different objects, because the **hashCode** is different and that is why both conditions are **False** (which is how it should be).

Feels like I need to fill the knowledge gap and will appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And to compare arrays you should use `Arrays.equals()`

Comment: There are plenty of websites explaining how hash codes work, such as https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perceived problem here lies in your understanding of the `hashCode`-method and the `equals` method for arrays.

The `hashCode` method can be found in `Object` and will create a hash based on the objects reference.

The `String` class overrides this method with its own logic based on calculations done on the `char`s of the `String` (more precisely it calculates the hash with the formula `s[0]*31^(n - 1) + s[1]*31^(n - 2) + ... + s[n - 1]` where `s[i]` is the `i`-th character of the `String`). This means that for 2 `Strings` that `equal` each other you will always get the same result by calling `hashCode`.

The `int[]` instead uses the implementation in `Object` therefore creating the hash from the object reference.
This means that for 2 arrays with equal values you will still get a different result by calling `hashCode`.

Also to compare the values of two arrays use `Arrays.equals` as calling `int[].equals` is the same as using the `==` operator which goes - once again - for reference comparison. `Arrays.equals` instead calls the `equals` method on every element in the array and will return a result based on their equality.

Comment: Could you also explain why `a.equals(b) - false` for the arrays? I think that is also an important part

Comment: @Ben thank you for the detailed answer! Yes, it is true, I read the same literally a minute ago, probably should have been more patient before posting this question online. Thank you!

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I've just looked at Java standard library. When it comes to String, `equals()` method is already overridden, so it is working as you would expect. On the other side, with arrays is it written by default.